# How to get google plus user image?

Tags: javascript, json, google-plus

I tried to search on stackoverflow but all answer not work.

This is my code for get google plus user image, but not work.

How can i do that ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignin(e){
      accessToken = e.access_token;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/");
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      xhr.send();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4){
          var myProfile = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          alert(myProfile.image.url);
        }
      }
    }
    </script>      
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:plus action="connect" clientid="100009709084787102522" scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" callback="onSignin">
    </g:plus>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i not get anything

Comment: Look in your browser's dev tools console and network tab.

Comment: to make a valid question, show us the exact errors or at what point functions dont get reached. use the debugger.